# Using images in haskell with gloss

Tags: haskell

I'm using gloss for the graphics of a game in haskell and I want to add pictures. I'm building a snake game and I'd like the apple to be an actual apple and not just a green circle (using Gloss.circleSolid). Is there a way to add pictures and not only use builtin in gloss?

Comment: is `bitmap` an option? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.11.1.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html#v:bitmap

Comment: What is bitmapdata though? what is this type?

Comment: This is why [gloss-juicy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-juicy) exists.  Slightly OT, but since you're learning you might like my [mellow](https://github.com/TomMD/mellow) library which glues gloss, friday, and kinect together.